# Optimal transport: how is the use of disintegration theorem valid in this construction of $\widetilde{\phi}$?

Tags: pr.probability, calculus-of-variations, optimal-transportation

Let $X,Y$ be Polish spaces and $\mathcal P(X)$ the space of all Borel probability measures on $X$.

- Fix $\mu\in \mathcal P(X), \nu \in \mathcal P(Y)$. Let $\pi \in \Pi(\mu, \nu)$, i.e., $\pi \in \mathcal P(X \times Y)$ whose marginal on $X$ is $\mu$ and that on $Y$ is $\nu$.
- Let $c:X \times Y \to [0, \infty)$ and $\psi:X \to \mathbb R \cup\{-\infty\}$ be measurable. Let $\phi:Y \to \mathbb R \cup\{-\infty\}$ which is **not** necessarily measurable.

We assume there is a $\sigma$-compact subset $S$ of $X \times Y$ such that

- $\pi (S) = 1$,
- $\psi (x), \phi (y) \neq -\infty$, and
- $\phi (y) - \psi (x)  = c(x, y)$ for all $(x, y) \in S$.

At page 84 of Villani's *Optimal Transport: Old and New*, the author constructs a **measurable** $\widetilde \phi: Y \to \mathbb R \cup \{\pm\infty\}$ such that $\widetilde \phi (y) = \phi (y)$ for $\nu$-a.e. $y\in Y$ as follows.

> The measurability of $\phi$ is subtle also, and at the present level of generality it is not clear that this function is really Borel measurable. However, it can be modified on a $\nu$-negligible set so as to become measurable. Indeed, $\phi(y)-\psi(x)=c(x, y), \pi(d x d y)$-almost surely, so if one disintegrates $\pi(d x d y)$ as $\pi(d x | y) \nu(d y)$, then $\phi(y)$ will coincide, $\nu(d y)$-almost surely, with the Borel function $\widetilde{\phi}(y) :=$ $\int_{\mathcal{X}}[\psi(x)+c(x, y)] \pi(d x | y)$.

I understand how the disintegration theorem leads to the family $\{\pi(d x | y)  : y \in Y\}$. Let $f(x, y) := c(x, y) - \varphi (x)$. Then $f$ is measurable and finite on $S$. I think the author uses claim 1. of this version of [disintegration theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4563738/disintegration-theorem-how-do-the-authors-prove-that-mu-y-is-supported-on?rq=1) to show that

- $\widetilde{\phi}(y)$ is well-defined, and
- $\widetilde{\phi}$ is measurable.

IMHO, disintegration theorem only applies to extended non-negative measurable and bounded measurable functions. We **don't** know if $f$ satisfies either conditions.

Could you elaborate on how the construction of $\widetilde{\phi}$ makes sense? Thank you so much.

---

I posted [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4579945/how-does-the-use-of-disintegration-theorem-make-sense-here) on MSE, but have not received any answer so far. So I post it here.

Comment: I had a look at this and I wasn’t able to resolve it either.. there are versions that hold for either nonnegative, bounded, or $L^1$ functions, but we cannot say that the integrand is any of these.

Comment: @NateRiver Thank you so much for your elaboration! I got it. Greinecker also came to the same [conclusion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4579945/how-does-the-use-of-disintegration-theorem-make-sense-here#comment9642448_4579945) as yours.

Comment: @NateRiver you meant that the function $f$ in claims 1. and 2. of [this version](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4563738/disintegration-theorem-how-do-the-authors-prove-that-mu-y-is-supported-on) can be generalized from being bounded measurable to being just $\mu$-integrable, right?

Comment: Indeed, I believe so.

Comment: @NateRiver In the linked version, $f \in L_\infty (\mu)$ and thus $h:y \mapsto \int_X f\mathrm d\mu_y$ belongs to $L_\infty (\nu)$. On the other hand, $g \in L_1 (\nu)$. So $hg \in L_1 (\nu)$ by Hölder's inequality. So it seems we can generalize to $f \in L_1 (\mu)$ with a trade-off that $g \in L_\infty (\nu)$.

Comment: @NateRiver Could you have a look at my closely related question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/435037/optimal-transport-the-existence-of-an-optimal-pair-of-c-conjugate-functions)?

Comment: Ha, I think that is beyond my skill level as well.. if it’s not available anywhere online you may well have to email people in the field.

Comment: @NateRiver I have sent an email to IEHS where Villani is currently working. They have forwarded my email to Villani. If we are lucky, we will get a reply from him...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140778/discussion-between-nate-river-and-akira).